# How to use a second query in a Promise in JS ? using mysql db

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, promise

Basically i got a createorder that needs to add the order into the database , and all the products in the order into an Orderline extra table.

Been trying different ways to get the second query to work but the only thing that gets inserted into the db is the data from the first query.

the second query also needs to use the id from the inserted order of the first query. since the database uses autoincrement for the id of the order.

```
CreateOrder: (req) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO web3.orders (Created, firstName, lastName, street, number, postalCode, city, telephone, email, totalPrice) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);';
            const sqlInsert2 = 'INSERT INTO web3.orderline (orderId,productId,qty,price) VALUES (?,?,?,?);';

            db.query(sqlInsert, [
                req.body.Created,
                req.body.firstName,
                req.body.lastName,
                req.body.street,
                req.body.number,
                req.body.postalCode,
                req.body.city,
                req.body.telephone,
                req.body.email,
                req.body.totalPrice],
                (err, result, fields) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve(result);

                    }
                });
                db.query(sqlInsert2,
                    [
                        result.insertId,
                        req.body.producten.id,
                        req.body.producten.cartQuantity,
                        req.body.producten.price], (err, result, fields) => {
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                resolve(result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need two promises: one for each query. And the second one should be created only when the first has resolved.

A nice way to do this, is to *promisify* `db.query` into a new function, and only use that function from then on. So define this first:

```
const promiseQuery = (sql, params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    db.query(sql, params, (err, result, fields) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(result))
);
```

Secondly, you can make your `CreateOrder` an `async` function so that you can use `await`:

```
async CreateOrder: (req) => {
    const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO web3.orders (Created, firstName, lastName, street, number, postalCode, city, telephone, email, totalPrice) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);';
    const sqlInsert2 = 'INSERT INTO web3.orderline (orderId,productId,qty,price) VALUES (?,?,?,?);';
    let result = await promiseQuery(sqlInsert, [
        req.body.Created,
        req.body.firstName,
        req.body.lastName,
        req.body.street,
        req.body.number,
        req.body.postalCode,
        req.body.city,
        req.body.telephone,
        req.body.email,
        req.body.totalPrice
    ]);
    await promiseQuery(sqlInsert2, [
        result.insertId,
        req.body.producten.id,
        req.body.producten.cartQuantity,
        req.body.producten.price
    ]);
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work , it does the same as before , only adds the order but not the data into the orderline table

Comment: is there any error in the above flow or the second query has not been executed? @kennycallens

Comment: @SmritiShikha the first order gets executed the it just shows POST /order500. the info from the first query is also inserted into the database fine.

Comment: What is the database API you are using (`db`)? What does debugging (with step by step execution, inspecting, ...) give you? Do these `INSERT` statements work (with the same values) when executed directly via the native user interface of the database?

Comment: @trincot mysql workbench https://gyazo.com/55c921231fba97254410cfcb351da182  erm im using visual studio code , this is my first js project but i don't think there is a step by step debugger like in vs2019 and c# when i manually insert them with the same values it works https://gyazo.com/821323d8b7eb6f12ac55bcc76e5462ec

Comment: Did you print every value that is involved during execution? Did you print some debugging info after each query, ...etc, ...etc. I cannot really help you further, as the code I posted is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

the above code is correct same flow works here

```
async function CreateOrder(req) {
    const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO legs (leg) VALUES (?);';
    const sqlInsert2 = 'INSERT INTO destinations (destination,area) VALUES (?,?);';
    let result = await promiseQuery(sqlInsert, [
        "lw"
    ]);
  let res=   await promiseQuery(sqlInsert2, [
        "test",
        "test location"
    ]);
    console.log(res)
}

const promiseQuery = (sql, params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    db.query(sql, params, (err, result, fields) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(result))
);
async function test(){
   await CreateOrder()
}
```

try checking if any of the key is undefined or there is a mismatch in the field type and the value you are passing

**if you req.body.producten is an array** you have to do the query for each iteration

```
async CreateOrder: (req) => {
    const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO web3.orders (Created, firstName, lastName, street, number, postalCode, city, telephone, email, totalPrice) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);';
    const sqlInsert2 = 'INSERT INTO web3.orderline (orderId,productId,qty,price) VALUES (?,?,?,?);';
    let result = await promiseQuery(sqlInsert, [
        req.body.Created,
        req.body.firstName,
        req.body.lastName,
        req.body.street,
        req.body.number,
        req.body.postalCode,
        req.body.city,
        req.body.telephone,
        req.body.email,
        req.body.totalPrice
    ]);
    for (let ele of req.body.producten){
        await promiseQuery(sqlInsert2, [
           result.insertId,
           ele.id,
           ele.cartQuantity,
           ele.price
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: the second query values are members of an array (  result.insertId,
        req.body.producten.id,
        req.body.producten.cartQuantity,
        req.body.producten.price) but the values are delivered it says here:  https://gyazo.com/93aa4c1a0f4ac50cf93978fe31fd5697

Comment: you want to insert all the elements of array as new row in mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CreateOrder: (req) => {
        const { Created, firstName, lastName, street, number, postalCode, city, telephone, email, totalPrice } = req.body
        let results = {}
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO web3.orders (Created, firstName, lastName, street, number, postalCode, city, telephone, email, totalPrice) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);';
            const sqlInsert2 = 'INSERT INTO web3.orderline (orderId,productId,qty,price) VALUES (?,?,?,?);';

            db.query(sqlInsert, [Created, firstName, lastName, street, number, postalCode, city, telephone, email, totalPrice],
                (err, result, fields) => {
                    console.log(result)
                    results.insertId = result.id
                });
            db.query(sqlInsert2, [ results.insertId, req.body.producten.id, req.body.producten.cartQuantity, req.body.producten.price], (err, result, fields) => {
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                resolve(result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
            }
```

I'm guessing in your initial code you're resolving the promise in the first `db.query` which results in ending the promise.